# how to ask for confirmation for multiple forms when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to ask for confirmation before deleting a user.
I have multiple forms in one page.

**The script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.delform input#delete_btn[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        if(!confirm("are you sure?")) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**The form:**

```
<form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="delform">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="2">
    <input type="submit" value="delete" id="delete_btn">
</form>
```

The problem is: the confirmation dialog does not appear when I submit the form. it just submits the form without asking for confirmation, it did work before I started using jquery.

in the page I'm using jquery 1.10.2 and jquery mobile 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this work well:**

```
$('form.delform input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        if(!confirm("are you sure?")) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with jQuery mobile but I know there's a lot of loading through AJAX going on. You can try to use event delegation.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.delform', function(e){
  return confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```

Doing it through the submit event is safer because you can submit a form without clicking a button.